# How can we solve "Travelling Salesman Problem" without returning to first point in the end?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, matrix

This is Traveling Salesman Problem. I need help because I don't understand how to make us start and end at different points.
Below I have given the code for solving the problem in the usual way. Here we start and end at the same point.

```
def Min(lst,myindex):
    return min(x for idx, x in enumerate(lst) if idx != myindex)

def Delete(matrix,index1,index2):
    del matrix[index1]
    for i in matrix:
        del i[index2]
    return matrix

def PrintMatrix(matrix):
    print("---------------")
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[i])
    print("---------------")

n=int(input())
matrix=[]
H=0
PathLenght=0
Str=[]
Stb=[]
res=[]
result=[]
StartMatrix=[]

for i in range(n):
    Str.append(i)
    Stb.append(i)

for i in range(n): matrix.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
    
for i in range(n):StartMatrix.append(matrix[i].copy())

float(inf)
for i in range(n): matrix[i][i]=float('inf')

while True:
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        temp=min(matrix[i])
        H+=temp
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            matrix[i][j]-=temp
 
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        temp = min(row[i] for row in matrix)
        H+=temp
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            matrix[j][i]-=temp
    
    NullMax=0
    index1=0
    index2=0
    tmp=0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if matrix[i][j]==0:
                tmp=Min(matrix[i],j)+Min((row[j] for row in matrix),i)
                if tmp>=NullMax:
                    NullMax=tmp
                    index1=i
                    index2=j

    res.append(Str[index1]+1)
    res.append(Stb[index2]+1)
    
    oldIndex1=Str[index1]
    oldIndex2=Stb[index2]
    if oldIndex2 in Str and oldIndex1 in Stb:
        NewIndex1=Str.index(oldIndex2)
        NewIndex2=Stb.index(oldIndex1)
        matrix[NewIndex1][NewIndex2]=float('inf')
    del Str[index1]
    del Stb[index2]
    matrix=Delete(matrix,index1,index2)
    if len(matrix)==1:break
    
for i in range(0,len(res)-1,2):
    if res.count(res[i])<2:
        result.append(res[i])
        result.append(res[i+1])
for i in range(0,len(res)-1,2):
    for j in range(0,len(res)-1,2):
        if result[len(result)-1]==res[j]:
            result.append(res[j])
            result.append(res[j+1])
print("----------------------------------")
print(result)

for i in range(0,len(result)-1,2):
    if i==len(result)-2:
        PathLenght+=StartMatrix[result[i]-1][result[i+1]-1]
        PathLenght+=StartMatrix[result[i+1]-1][result[0]-1]
    else: PathLenght+=StartMatrix[result[i]-1][result[i+1]-1]
print(PathLenght)
print("----------------------------------")
input()
```

This code works like this:

1. input 4
2. input 4x4 matrix like this:

```
0 10 1 1
10 0 1 5
1 1 0 10
1 5 10 0
```

3. result: 1->4 4->2 2->3 3->1
   (8)

I done this question like this on JS:

```
let towns = [
  [0, 28, 58, 13, 24, 25, 31, 64],
  [28, 0, 82, 15, 52, 27, 33, 54],
  [58, 82, 0, 67, 82, 64, 49, 97],
  [13, 15, 67, 0, 37, 12, 18, 69],
  [24, 52, 82, 37, 0, 49, 53, 40],
  [25, 27, 64, 12, 49, 0, 15, 81],
  [31, 33, 49, 18, 53, 15, 0, 70],
  [64, 54, 97, 69, 40, 81, 70, 0],
];

let path = [];
let counter = 0;
let minPath = 10000;
let minCounter;

for (let i1 = 0; i1 <= 7; i1++) {
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 <= 7; i2++) {
    for (let i3 = 0; i3 <= 7; i3++) {
      for (let i4 = 0; i4 <= 7; i4++) {
        for (let i5 = 0; i5 <= 7; i5++) {
          for (let i6 = 0; i6 <= 7; i6++) {
            for (let i7 = 0; i7 <= 7; i7++) {
              for (let i8 = 0; i8 <= 7; i8++) {
                if (
                  i1 != i2 &&
                  i1 != i3 &&
                  i1 != i4 &&
                  i1 != i5 &&
                  i1 != i6 &&
                  i1 != i7 &&
                  i1 != i8 &&
                  i2 != i3 &&
                  i2 != i4 &&
                  i2 != i5 &&
                  i2 != i6 &&
                  i2 != i7 &&
                  i2 != i8 &&
                  i3 != i4 &&
                  i3 != i5 &&
                  i3 != i6 &&
                  i3 != i7 &&
                  i3 != i8 &&
                  i4 != i5 &&
                  i4 != i6 &&
                  i4 != i7 &&
                  i4 != i8 &&
                  i5 != i6 &&
                  i5 != i7 &&
                  i5 != i8 &&
                  i6 != i7 &&
                  i6 != i8 &&
                  i7 != i8
                ) {
                  path[counter] =
                    i1 +
                    1 +
                    " → " +
                    (i2 + 1) +
                    " → " +
                    (i3 + 1) +
                    " → " +
                    (i4 + 1) +
                    " → " +
                    (i5 + 1) +
                    " → " +
                    (i6 + 1) +
                    " → " +
                    (i7 + 1) +
                    " → " +
                    (i8 + 1);
                  console.log(path[counter]);
                  if (
                    towns[i1][i2] +
                      towns[i2][i3] +
                      towns[i3][i4] +
                      towns[i4][i5] +
                      towns[i5][i6] +
                      towns[i6][i7] +
                      towns[i7][i8] <
                    minPath
                  ) {
                    minPath =
                      towns[i1][i2] +
                      towns[i2][i3] +
                      towns[i3][i4] +
                      towns[i4][i5] +
                      towns[i5][i6] +
                      towns[i6][i7] +
                      towns[i7][i8];
                    console.log(minPath);
                    minCounter = counter;
                  }
                  counter += 1;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(
  "Shortest Way: " +
    path[minCounter] +
    "(" +
    minPath +
    " KM.)"
);
```

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer what I need help with :(

Comment: Start at the end of the longest/heaviest/dearest edge (and end at its start, never travelling it).

Comment: @greybeard That won't find all examples. E.g., sps we have a complete graph on n >= 6 vertices. We'll distinguish 6: a, b, c, d, e, f. Say (a, b) is the most expensive edge at cost 100, and say c has cost 99 edges to every vertex but e, and d has cost 99 edges to every vertex but f. All other edges are cost 1. Best solution starts at c with the (c, e) edge, and ends at d with the (f, e) edge (and of course doesn't use the (a, b) edge).

Comment: (@Dave: `ends at d with the (f, e) edge`?) I may have been overly terse: Start at the end of the longest/heaviest/dearest edge *of one TSP solution*.

Comment: @greybeard Typo: should read "...ends at e with the (f,e) edge. The point is that there is one most-expensive edge, and two other vertices with only one cheap edge, and all other edges are cheap. Then the cheapest solution will start and end at the vertices with only one cheap edge (other edges being not quite as expensive as the most-expensive edge), and the solution will use one of many paths that goes through the endpoints of the most-expensive edge without passing through it.

Comment: @greybeard Simpler example on a not-complete graph: verts a,b,c,d,e. Edges: ab=100, ac=1, ae=1, bd=1, be=1, cd=99, ce=99, de=99, no other edges. Any solution that starts at a and ends at b (both sides of the expensive edge) must include at least 1 of the cost 99 edges, but c,a,e,b,d visits all vertices and uses only cost 1 edges.

Comment: (@Dave: ab is the most expensive edge *in the graph*, but not part of any TSP solution. One TSP solution is *caebdc*: starting at the end of the "99 edge" *dc* you get *caebd*… Anyway, your construction is "obviously*correct, and until someone proves my suggestion correct, no-one needs to bother to about the difference in performance.)

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra node to be your starting point, with a zero-cost edge to every other node and solve the regular TSP, then throw out the added node.